# Bootstrap dropdown not expanding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap dropdown is not working. I can see the dropdown results within the same area as the dropdown label if I scroll down, but the dropdown results are not expanding.

Comment: If this is an answer to another question then post it as an answer there. If you just want to share something useful then write it up as a proper good question and answer it yourself with the solution. Currently this is a low quality question and might be removed due to that.

Comment: Please provide a complete question and add your post as an answer.

Comment: Should I post the answer to myself in a separate post? There are a lot of other posts on this issue, but the correct answer was already set to something like importing order for the javascript files. Should I post it there instead?

Comment: Yes, I think you should. This post is a possibly a duplicate of those posts.

Answer (score 0):

I original had overflow set to auto for all elements (which accidentally included the dropdown divs:

```
body, div {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Removing this made it work.